# Buffon's needle problem - mistake in a book?

Tags: probability, trigonometry

I was reading today in the book "[The number $\pi$](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821832468)" (Eymard, Lafon) about the famed Buffon's needle problem. Assume that every strip (two adjacent rays) is of height $d$ and that the needle is of length $\ell <d$. Now, look at the angle $\vartheta$ between the center of the needle and the perpendicular line to the rays. Also, define $t$ as the distance between the center of the needle to the closest ray. I think that the formula $$t=\frac{\ell}{2}\cos \vartheta$$ is wrong.

Am I wrong?[image]

Comment: What do you think the formula should be?

Comment: Looks okay to me. What makes you think it's wrong? (I agree the book's explanation is very terse.)

Comment: If you move the needle up and down without changing the angle $t$ changes but $\ell$ and $\vartheta$ don't.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan, the formula $t=(\ell/2)\cos\theta$ describes the curve that separates values of $t$ for which the needle stays within a single strip from values for which the needle does not.

Comment: @BarryCipra Look at figure 1.27. Is the formula correct? If it is, I would glad to understand how. Notice that the point $A$ doesn't lie on $\Omega_1$.

Comment: Look at that arrow. It indicates that $t=\frac{L}{2}\cos\theta$ is the equation of the curve separating the shaded region from the white region.

Comment: @TonyK OK - now I understood. Thank you

Comment: Not an answer, but you might enjoy https://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/whypi.pdf and other links at https://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks! there's also a fantastic chapter in the fantastic book "Proofs from the book".

Answer (score 2):

Well Strictly speaking you are correct insofar as the formula
$$
t = \frac{l}{2}\cos \theta
$$
is wrong.

But the book does not claim that this is a formula that always holds.

Comment: Thanks - understood.